# Wordpad loses pasted images after reopening

Tags: windows, images, rtf, wordpad

This is affecting just one computer of many I have access to, all running Windows XP Professional. I copy a selection from an image in MSPaint then paste into Wordpad. I save, close and reopen and the image and any text after it is gone. The image selection is generally small in size.

- I can do exactly the same operation on the other computers and everything works fine.
- I found one [example](http://www.technologyquestions.com/technology/windows-xp/66764-trouble-retaing-wordpad-images-rich-text-format.html) of someone else on the internet having the same problem but he didn't get a solution.
- A program we use that uses a richtextbox is exhibiting the same problem, again only on this computer.
- Finally MS Word is also installed and it has no problems.
- It doesn't happen ALL the time just most of the time and it only seems to have started recently

Comment: If you cannot recreate the conditions exactly every time, then it is likely that you are not understanding the problem correctly.

Comment: That's true but so far it's the bug that's reproducible  not normal behaviour, that happens on a seemingly random basis.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue with a machine here.  I found that by first putting in a different image (hand drew a picture in mspaint, cut and paste part of it into the wordpad doc), it would allow me to use the other images (.jpg from a camera).

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I encountered the problem when I was trying to copy and paste images of file formats other than BMP (bitmap).

Later I converted those image files (`.jpg`, `.jpeg`, `.png` etc) to `.bmp` (bitmap) format, copied them to Wordpad, and saved it.